# Parsing Multiple PDFs as a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdf

How do I copy the contents of the entire PDF (of multiple PDFs in a folder) in a single cell (say, column B) and file name in column A? Right now, this code parses all PDFs, but each line in PDF is saved a separate row in the dataframe. I need each PDF as a single row.

```
from pathlib import Path
import fitz
import pandas as pd

# returns all file paths that has .pdf as extension in the specified directory
fold = "C:/Users/talen/OneDrive/Application Development/data/ForParse/"
pdf_search = Path(fold).glob("*.pdf")
# convert the glob generator out put to list

pdf_files = pdf_files = [str(file.absolute()) for file in pdf_search]

pdf_txt = ""
for pdf in pdf_files:
    with fitz.open(pdf) as doc:
        
        for page in doc:
            pdf_txt += page.getText()


with open('pdf_txt.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as f: #Converting to text file
    f.write(pdf_txt)

data=pd.read_table('pdf_txt.txt', lineterminator='\n')  #Converting text file to dataframe
print(data)
```

I also tried using a "sep='\n'" which gives me an error: ValueError: Specified \n as separator or delimiter. This forces the python engine which does not accept a line terminator. Hence it is not allowed to use the line terminator as separator.

Comment: Why do you have to save the text to a file only to read it back in?  I would think you'd be better off creating an empty Dataframe and then adding the text to it from memory.  That way, you don't have to worry about how the text gets parsed, as you're avoiding the parsing step completely.

Comment: You are right. I can do away with the text file bit, although struggling to actually get the code which helps me save each PDF as a row in a dataframe: Filename -- PDF Contents. The idea is once I have this dataframe, I am going to run a script I have that classifies this dataframe using a pretrained model, will add keywords per row, and also add sentiment score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you do not need to convert the PDF file to Text file. Rather you can directly paste the text of the PDF file into any cell of the dataframe.

1. Create an empty list `textStr=[]` to store the text of the PDF file using `textStr.append(Page.get_text("text").replace('\n',' '))`. Here you need to iterate through the pages of the PDF file.
2. Join the items of the list `textStr=[]` to form a string `Text=' '.join(textStr)`.
3. Now paste the string `Text` at any location in the dataframe, say at second(**1**) row and **B** th column given by `df.at[1,'B']=Text`

Comment: That was good direction. Thanks. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly here, but each page is being saved as a separate row. I need each file as a separate row (with a file name in column 1, for example).   

**
textStr=[]

for pdf in pdf_files:
    with fitz.open(pdf) as doc:
        
        for page in doc:
            textStr.append(page.getText("text").replace('\n',' '))
            # Text=' '.join(textStr)
        

# df.at[1,'B']=Text

df = pd.DataFrame(textStr)

print(df)**